# Difference between INT_MIN , INT8_MIN , INT16_MIN. For MAX too

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

In VScode, I was using `INT_MIN`/`INT_MAX`, But today I got an error, saying "Unidentified Classifier". Instead it suggested me to use `INT8_MIN`.

After using this it worked perfectly.

But, what is the core difference between them ?

Comment: *"After using this it worked perfectly".* You mean "it **compiled** perfectly". There is a difference. Trust me, it won't "**work** perfectly" at all. INT_MIN/INT_MAX have a min/max value allowed for "generic" `int`, while INT8_MIN/INT8_MAX are definitions for a min/max value of an int of 8 bits defined as `std::int8_t`. See *<cstdint>* and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer .

Comment: If you're really interested in using c++ then look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits

Comment: I would also recommend a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Oh those are all left-overs from "C" don't use them, use the link @RetiredNinja already sent you. Looks like you are learning C++ from an outdated source.

Comment: Some good resources to learn C++ from are [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) for your initial steps (it is very decent for an online tutorial). 
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to lookup everything C++ has to offer. 
And finally use the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with how C++ evolves and how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: `INT_MIN` is defined in the header <limits.h> but `INT8_MIN` is defined in the header <stdint.h>. That probably explains the compilation error. They are also different values, which seems like the more serious problem.

Comment: `INT_MIN` is the minimum possible value that an `int` (which will be represented using *at least* 16 bits) can represent.     If your compiler supports `std::int8_t` (it is optional but, if provided, is in `<cstdint>`) then `INT8_MIN` is the minimum possible value that an `std::int8_t` (an 8-bit type) can represent.    I wouldn't normally expect a compiler to suggest using `INT8_MIN` instead of `INT_MIN` unless your code is actually using `std::int8_t` in some way  (mixing integral types of different sizes does implicit conversions, so can produce unexpected results).

Answer (score 4):

Your code might compile now, but it will not work as you expect. The `INT8_*` macros have totally different values than the `INT_*` ones.

`INT_MIN`/`INT_MAX` are the min/max values for an `int` (and are defined in `<limits.h>` header).
It is typically **32 bit** and therefore the values that you used before were probably **–2147483648** and **2147483647** respectively (they could be larger for 64 bit integers, or smaller for 16 bit ones).

On the other hand `INT8_MIN`/`INT8_MAX`are min/max values for a **8 bit** signed integer (AKA `int8_t`), which are **-128** and **127** respectively. BTW - they are also defined in a different header (`<stdint.h>`) which might explain why using it solved your compilation error.

**The bottom line:**
In order to get the behavior you had before, you should use `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` and `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, from the [`<limits>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

Note that `INT_MIN` and similar constants are actually macros "inherited" from C. In C++ we prefer to use the `std::numeric_limit` template (mentioned above) which accepts the type as a template agrument. This makes is less likely to make mistakes. You could even use `decltype(variable)` as the the template agrument.

Finally - you also mentioned `INT16_MIN`/`INT16_MAX` in your title: it is the correlative min/max values for **16 bit** signed integer - i.e. **-32768** and **32767** respectively. The same principle applies to similar constants. Again they have an equivalent in `std::numeric_limits` which is recommended in C++.

Comment: Yep; the macros are kind of a bad idea since you have to choose the appropiate one yourself. With the limits header, you provide the type that you're using -- which could even be a template parameter, or a `decltype(variable)` -- so it's more likely to be the correct one.

Comment: @ChristianStieber I added a note emphasising this point.

Comment: @wohlstad The two macros are also defined in different headers, which I guess is why one compiles and one doesn't for the OP.